# Graph line disappears when plotting graphs using 2 dataframes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

My graph lines for the first subplot (ax1) completely disappears after plotting `df1['Volume (BTC)'].plot(label='EUR Volume')`. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.read_csv('eurPrice.csv', index_col='Timestamp', parse_dates=True)
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
df['sourceA'].plot(label='sourceA')
df['sourceB'].plot(label='sourceB')
plt.legend()

ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex = ax1)
df1 = pd.read_csv('eurVolume.csv', index_col='Timestamp', parse_dates=True)
df1['Volume (BTC)'].plot(label='EUR Volume')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the plot as an image?

Comment: have you tried `df1['Volume (BTC)'].plot(label='EUR Volume',ax=ax2)` ?

Comment: @tom tried your suggestion but it doesn't work